# VS Studio 2017 offline installer download

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, download, visual-studio-2017, offline

I Downloaded the Visual Studio Community and run this in my cmd.

```
vs_community.exe --layout c:\vs2017layout --lang en-US
```

I just follow this on [Install Visual Studio 2017 on low bandwidth or unreliable network environments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/install-vs-inconsistent-quality-network)

Tha layout is already on 26.6GB, how many more should I wait? and also It suddenly running the powershell.exe with some parameters is this an error? or is it still downloading?

This is now what my vs console run and not the usual update layout

Running: "'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe' and some long parameters and arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not an error, it's still downloading just wait for it

Comment: Before installing from your current layout, was there a VS already installed? If having VS already installed though from offline layout but not same path as your current layout, update will not use your current layout. You need to uninstall your VS and reinstall from your current layout.